# RESTful resource with an expensive property

Tags: rest

I have a resource /messages.

In my java code, the Message interface looks like this:

```java
interface Message {
    public int getID();
    public int getPostingUserID();
    public String getText();
    public int getRelevance();
}
```

For example, /messages/7 will give the following:

```
{ id: 7, postingUserID: 102, text: "tabs are better!", relevance: 10.3 }
```

Unfortunately, getRelevance() is quite expensive to calculate on-the-fly, and is only needed for perhaps a tenth of the queries. I don't want to calculate it when I don't need it.

So, I can see a few options:

- /messages/7?includeRelevance=true to tell it to calculate the relevance, otherwise don't include it in the response
- /messages/7/relevance as a separate request, and calculate it then
- /relevances?forMessageID=7 as a separate request, and calculate it then

Which option is the most RESTful?

Thanks!

Comment: They all seem RESTful to me. Maybe you are overthinking this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to go for `/messages/7/relevance` in this situation, and I'd *make sure* that the document returned when fetching `/messages/7` includes a URL to the relevant relevance resource (for HATEOAS discoverability, of course).

Comment: +1 cleanest, most discoverable and, above all, most understandable.

Comment: awesome, thanks! so would i return something like this for /messages/7?

    { id: 7, postingUserID: 102, text: "tabs are better!", relevanceURI: "/messages/7/relevance" }

Comment: @Verdagon That sort of thing sounds OK. I personally prefer to return XML documents to JSON as I can embed/link deeper type metadata like that, but that's definitely personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

The most RESTful way to do this (I believe, and could definitely be wrong) is to define 2 different media-types.

The client can request a specific one with the `Accept:` header, and you could default to the minimal one.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I don't know! Do media-types need to be discoverable? I imagine that whatever links to the resource could include a type="" attribute, but I think the assumption with REST is that the client needs to be aware of the mediatypes anyway to really make sense of the responses.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I'm asking for a message, and then not returning a message? Seems misleading. I thought media-types were to specify the format, not what the data means (but then again, I know nothing of REST)